# zsh (mac big sur) Can't Recognize pip install

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I recently started using zsh with oh-my-zch. I then ran into trouble of not able to do simply pip install command. I checked the version: it shows 2.7.16 for 'python --version' and '3.8.2' for 'python3 --version'.
When I type 'pip install ipython', it gave me this error
'zsh: correct 'ipython' to '.ipython' [nyae]? '
Then I type 'n', and it gave me this as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==21.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2843, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2434, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2440, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-21.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Then when I type 'pip3 install ipython', it gave me as below:

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: ipython in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (7.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython) (50.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.16 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython) (0.18.0)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.2 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython) (5.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: appnope in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython) (0.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython) (3.0.18)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect>4.3 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython) (4.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: parso<0.9.0,>=0.8.0 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from jedi>=0.16->ipython) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from pexpect>4.3->ipython) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython) (0.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from traitlets>=4.2->ipython) (0.2.0)
```

I didn't have this problem until I upgraded it to big sur. I was not using python after the upgrade until now. I tried bash, same problem.

Here's my zshrc file.

```
# Enable Powerlevel10k instant prompt. Should stay close to the top of ~/.zshrc.
# Initialization code that may require console input (password prompts, [y/n]
# confirmations, etc.) must go above this block; everything else may go below.
if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
fi



POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(context dir vcs virtualenv)
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/Users/dandan/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="agnoster"


# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in $ZSH/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to automatically update without prompting.
# DISABLE_UPDATE_PROMPT="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# Caution: this setting can cause issues with multiline prompts (zsh 5.7.1 and newer seem to work)
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/5765
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
# Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=( git zsh-syntax-highlighting zsh-autosuggestions )

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

if [ -x "$(command -v colorls)" ]; then
    alias ls="colorls"
    alias la="colorls -al"
fi 
# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
# source ~/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme

# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh

# Find python file
alias pyfind='find . -name "*.py"'

if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi

# Remove python compiled byte-code and mypy/pytest cache in either the current
# directory or in a list of specified directories (including sub directories).
function pyclean() {
    ZSH_PYCLEAN_PLACES=${*:-'.'}
    find ${ZSH_PYCLEAN_PLACES} -type f -name "*.py[co]" -delete
    find ${ZSH_PYCLEAN_PLACES} -type d -name "__pycache__" -delete
    find ${ZSH_PYCLEAN_PLACES} -depth -type d -name ".mypy_cache" -exec rm -r "{}" +
    find ${ZSH_PYCLEAN_PLACES} -depth -type d -name ".pytest_cache" -exec rm -r "{}" +
}

# Add the user installed site-packages paths to PYTHONPATH, only if the
#   directory exists. Also preserve the current PYTHONPATH value.
# Feel free to autorun this when .zshrc loads.
function pyuserpaths() {
    local targets=("python2" "python3")  # bins
    
    # Get existing interpreters.
    local interps=()
    for target in $targets; do
        [ `command -v $target` ] && interps+=($target)
    done

    # Check for a non-standard install directory.
    local user_base="${HOME}/.local"
    [ $PYTHONUSERBASE ] && user_base=$PYTHONUSERBASE

    # Add version specific paths, if:
    #   it exists in the filesystem;
    #   it isn't in PYTHONPATH already.
    for interp in $interps; do
        # Get minor release version.
        local ver=`$interp -V 2>&1`
        ver=`echo ${ver:7} | cut -d '.' -f 1,2`  # The patch version is variable length, truncate it.
        
        local site_pkgs="${user_base}/lib/python${ver}/site-packages"
        [[ -d $site_pkgs && ! $PYTHONPATH =~ $site_pkgs ]] && export PYTHONPATH=${site_pkgs}:$PYTHONPATH
    done
}

# Grep among .py files
alias pygrep='grep -nr --include="*.py"'
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3

# Run proper IPython regarding current virtualenv (if any)
alias ipython="python -c 'import IPython; IPython.terminal.ipapp.launch_new_instance()'"
```

Could anyone tell me how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Try `python -m pip install -U pip && python -m pip install ipython` for python 2.7 and `python3 -m pip install -U pip && python3 -m pip install ipython` for python 3.8.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

try:

"sudo easy_install pip"

otherwise, try "pip3 install...